# Unable to use aa-genprof without compatibility patch

Tags: arch-linux, apparmor

I run 3.6.10 kernel,

It seems like apparmor compatibility patch were dropped in latest kernel, so aa-genprof won't work anymore, any suggestions?

Looks like aa-status or other aa- commands were trying to access a non-existence location `/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles`

P.S securityfs was mounted,

`securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`